# Why would a closed question be hot?

Tags: support, closed-questions, hot-questions

Just went to the hot tab on stackoverflow.com and saw a question that was closed there.  Why?  I would figure that something that's closed really isn't all that hot and should be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Hot is tracking things that measure as incredibly active with views and comments and answers over a period of time. It has nothing to do about the overall quality of the question.

Comment: I see that but if something is closed it would be nice to not have to see it . . . especially in something labeled "hot".  I guess I should just stick to "active" since nothing looks closed there.

Comment: Just because it was closed does not mean that it won't be reopened. Often times a closed question will be host because there is a lot of discussion over whether or not it should be reopened and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

Bikeshed-style questions could be both hot, because lots of people want to participate, and closed, because the question may not be suitable for a Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

It was busy, so it's hot, but maybe they could set it so that if it closed it wouldn't be hot anymore (or active).

Comment: I disagree with the second part of your response.  The community votes to *reopen* questions too, so I think closed question have as much right to be seen as open ones.

Comment: Well, if that's the case I guess I kind of see it . . . just sucks because closed questions seem to be useless.  I'm guessing that after so many down votes it does go away and that's precisely the point.  Why a comment and not an answer?!

Comment: I agree that after a certain period of time closed questions should just go away.  It would be unfair to hide them as soon as they're closed though, since that would take away their opportunity to be reopened.  If they're still hot, they should be just as visible.  I commented instead of answering because I was really only responding to your answer, not directly to the question. :)